# Code refactor - EntityManager, ResourceModel and handlers

Tags: resource-model, crud, entity-manager

I have a slider module which use EntityManager.
I want to refactor code to use ResourceModel, but i have problem with many to many relations.
With EntityManager i used EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionPool with Read/SaveHandlers.
How to implement same functionality with ResourceModel?

Comment: Can you add some of the code that you are trying to change?